# how to find datediff by using date format as ARRDAT(20140523) and DEPDAT(20140815)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Date formats are different can any one help me with different date formats

how to find datediff by using date format as ARRDAT(20140523) and DEPDAT(20140815)

Comment: Your question needs more explanation.  Table layouts, sample data and desired results are always helpful, particularly for non-native speakers of English.

Comment: I have 2 different columns ARRDAT and DEPDAT by using that i want to find out total number of days.Date format is 20140525 like this only there in table..

Comment: Do you want to include dates in days calculation ? Also it would be kind if you can give the data type of the above two columns

Comment: In order to use datediff you need values in date datatype (date, datetime, datetime2). If your dates are not in a date datatype, you'll first have to convert them. So you'll probably end up with something like datediff(convert(datetime, arrdat), convert(datetime, depdat)). You may have to play around with the convert to get the proper result though.

Comment: `ARRDAT` and `DEPDAT` are column names?

Comment: ARRDAT & DEPDAT are column name, the datatype is long.

Answer (score 1):

The date format of the 2 values looks like `yyyyMMdd` which is the `ISO` date format.

Knowing this we can use the following:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, ArrivalDate, DepartureDate) AS DiffInDays
  FROM (
        SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(ARRDAT AS VARCHAR(8)), 112) AS ArrivalDate,
               CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(DEPDAT AS VARCHAR(8)), 112) AS DepartureDate
       ) AS t
```

`CAST(expression AS VARCHAR(8))` changes the `BIGINT` to a `VARCHAR` for the `CONVERT` function to work.

`CONVERT(DATETIME, expression, 112)` specifies the format of the data is `yyyyMMdd`.

Comment: Please note that I've separated the `SELECT` into two parts for readability only, and you could do all this on one line if desired.

Comment: You can actually just `cast(cast(ARRDATE as VARCHAR(8)) as date)`.  YYYYMMDD is an ISO standard format that SQL Server understands correctly, regardless of internationalization settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(    DAY, 
                    CAST(SUBSTRING(APPDAT,1,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(APPDAT,5,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(APPDAT,7,2) AS DATE), 
                    CAST(SUBSTRING(DEPDAT,1,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(DEPDAT,5,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(DEPDAT,7,2) AS DATE))
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks for ur Suggestion but this would be not enough solution.I want date conversion

Comment: SELECT ARRDAT,DEPDAT,
(DATEDIFF(DAY,(CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,ARRDAT))),(CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,DEPDAT)))))TOTDAY FROM FMOCCVEW

Comment: Hi guys i found Solution for this...Thanks for all